# Strange characters in console Python

Tags: python, encoding

Reading the word "beyoncè" from a text file, python is handling it as "beyonc\xc3\xa9".

If I write it into a file, it shows correctly, but in console It shows like that.

Also If I try to use it in my program I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how can I let Python read beyoncè from a text file as beyonce and getting rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
f= open('mytextfile.txt', encoding='utf-8', 'w') 
f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string="beyonc\xc3\xa9"
string.decode("utf-8")
foo=open("foo.txt","wb")
foo.write(string)
foo.close()
```